# Defining a static method on a specific type in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a method that calculate a percentage increase between two values.
And in my "class" it looks like this:

```
percIncrease(a, b) {
    let percent;
    if (b !== 0) {
      if (a !== 0) {
        percent = ((b - a) / a) * 100;
      } else {
        percent = b * 100;
      }
    } else {
      percent = -a * 100;
    }
    return percent.toFixed(3);
  }
```

now cause I want it reusable from everywhere, I am trying to define it on a type (Number), so I can use it everywhere.

I tried this:

```
Number.prototype.percIncrease = function (a, b) {
  let percent;
  if (b !== 0) {
    if (a !== 0) {
      percent = ((b - a) / a) * 100;
    } else {
      percent = b * 100;
    }
  } else {
    percent = -a * 100;
  }
  return percent.toFixed(3);
};
```

but if I try to use it like this :

```
Number.percIncrease(a,b);
```

> TypeError: Number.percIncrease is not a function

I am not that good in using Javascript terms, but what I am actually trying, is to declare a static method on a specific type (say, Number).

How I would do this?

EDIT:

Or it doesn't have to be static. Working on a value would do the job to. For example this (pseudo code):

```
myNumber.percIncrease(inCompareToValue: anotherNumber)
```

Comment: `prototype` methods will be available to each instance, not statically. If you want it to be available as `Number.percIncrease`, then define it there. But modifying builtins is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a method in the prototype, it's used when you call the method on an instance. Static methods should be added to the type directly, not the prototype:

```js
Number.percIncrease = function (a, b) {
  let percent;
  if (b !== 0) {
    if (a !== 0) {
      percent = ((b - a) / a) * 100;
    } else {
      percent = b * 100;
    }
  } else {
    percent = -a * 100;
  }
  return percent.toFixed(3);
};

console.log(Number.percIncrease(10, 15));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a fifferent call of the prototype and maybe change the style a bit.

```js
Number.prototype.percIncrease = function(base) {
    let percent;
    if (base) {
        percent = this
            ? (base - this) * 100 / this
            : base * 100;
    } else {
        percent = -this * 100;
    }
    return percent.toFixed(3);
};


console.log(5..percIncrease(4));
```

Comment: Yes, got it. I wasn't aware of how to add method on a type vs on an instance.

Answer (score 0):

call your function like that:

```
Number.prototype.percIncrease(1, 10); //"1,10" are examples
```